# Notifications to both primary and secondary email

Tags: notification, email

Would it make sense to allow the user to choose receiving email notifications to both their primary email and their secondary one? Or should I just limit the user to selecting just one?

Comment: In my opinion, you should send notification to just one email. Users should have the option to toggle their primary email. If you are sending sensitive information (like OTP, Security Codes, Password Recovery Links etc.) to both email, the risk gets doubled.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on why they have two emails set, if they are defined as primary / secondary etc. Showing a checkbox next to email with something like: Make this email primary ( all notifications / password reset / etc. will be send to this email ) would help clear this issue.

Answer (score 0):

*If email notifications are enabled, sending them only to the primary email is a sufficient option. It is more concise and requires less maintenance.*

The secondary email most common use is for access recovery only. Sending notifications that are not relevant to the access control to the secondary email seems like an overcomplication. If a user wants a different email for the regular notifications, he or she can make it the primary one at any time.